# dynamic, multiple input drop down, with a default starting value in R shiny app

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I was just wondering if anyone had any suggestions as to how this might be accomplished, I have looked at Rshiny sites toy examples that use `selectInput` and `selectizeInput`, however none of the examples seem to be able to extend to what I need to do. The general syntax for select/selectize is,

```
selectInput("ID", "Label", choices = c('a','b','c','d'), multiple = TRUE)
```

This works fine if I don't require a default starting value. However, I do. 
There also seems to be a way to get a default starting value to work, but not multiple values,

```
selectizeInput("ID", "Label", choices = c('a','b','c','d'),
               options = list(placeholder = '', onInitialize = 10))
```

I'm pretty new to shiny so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `selected=c("a", "b")` to a multiple select input or `selected="a"` to a single-select input (or any other values if your choices differ).

Source: Shiny help at `?selectInput`

More on selectInputs:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks for the quick reply!