# How to include a default input when you there multiple inputs allowed in the dropdown Flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to make the default selection when the application loads in the "Manufacturer drop down to be "ALL." Currently, the option is blank when the user loads into the application. Does anyone know how you would do this when you allow for multiple inputs?

Here's some example data to use:

```
structure(list(Toys = c("Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", 
"Slinky", "Slinky", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", 
"Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", 
"Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", "Bead Maze", "Hula Hoop", 
"Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", "Hula Hoop", 
"Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", 
"Kaleidoscope", "Kaleidoscope", "Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", 
"Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", "Pogo Stick", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", 
"Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", 
"Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Jump N' Dunk Trampoline", "Play-Doh", 
"Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Play-Doh", "Mr. Potato Head", 
"Mr. Potato Head", "Mr. Potato Head", "Mr. Potato Head", "Mr. Potato Head", 
"Mr. Potato Head", "Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", 
"Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", "Corn Popper", "Let's Go Fishing", 
"Let's Go Fishing", "Let's Go Fishing", "Let's Go Fishing", "Let's Go Fishing", 
"Let's Go Fishing", "Operation", "Operation", "Operation", "Operation", 
"Operation", "Operation", "Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", 
"Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", "Ker Plunk", "Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", 
"Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", "Jack-In-The-Box", 
"Xylophone", "Xylophone", "Xylophone", "Xylophone", "Xylophone", 
"Xylophone", "Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", 
"Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", "Chatter Phone", "Jumbo Jacks", 
"Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", "Jumbo Jacks", 
"Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", 
"Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", "Rock 'em Sock 'em Robots", 
"Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", 
"Silly Putty", "TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", 
"TinkerToy", "TinkerToy", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", 
"Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Silly Putty", "Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", 
"Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", "Red Wagon", "Magic 8 Ball", 
"Magic 8 Ball", "Magic 8 Ball", "Magic 8 Ball", "Magic 8 Ball", 
"Magic 8 Ball"), Manufacturer = c("Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", 
"Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", 
"Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", "Manufacturer E", 
"Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", 
"Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer G", "Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", 
"Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", "Manufacturer H", 
"Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", 
"Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer I", "Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", 
"Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", "Manufacturer J", 
"Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", 
"Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer K", "Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", 
"Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", "Manufacturer L", 
"Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", 
"Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer M", "Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", 
"Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", "Manufacturer N", 
"Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", 
"Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer O", "Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", 
"Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", "Manufacturer P", 
"Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", 
"Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer Q", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", 
"Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", 
"Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", 
"Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer S", "Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", 
"Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", "Manufacturer T", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", 
"Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", "Manufacturer D", 
"Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R", 
"Manufacturer R", "Manufacturer R"), Price = c(5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 
9, 6, 5.54, 7, 9.99, 6.99, 6.75, 8, 7.99, 9.99, 7.99, 5.99, 8.99, 
10.99, 9.75, 9.99, 10.15, 8.99, 6.99, 5.99, 9.99, 9.99, 7.75, 
8.75, 9.95, 4.5, 5.54, 3.99, 4.5, 7.5, 8.95, 8.9, 6.99, 150.99, 
175.99, 170.99, 180.99, 190.99, 175, 310.64, 335.64, 360.64, 
385.64, 410.64, 435.64, 7.99, 8.99, 9.05, 9.1, 9.99, 10.15, 6.75, 
8.75, 7.75, 9.75, 6.75, 8.75, 10.35, 10.55, 11, 17, 17.75, 18, 
6.97, 7.05, 8.97, 9, 8.99, 6.99, 19.99, 21.15, 16.99, 17.99, 
18.99, 14.99, 14.96, 14.97, 15.15, 18.17, 19, 50, 6, 7, 8, 7, 
9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 9, 5, 6, 7, 7.5, 5, 5, 10.95, 9.95, 
9.99, 10.5, 10.95, 9.95, 28, 30, 28, 32, 27, 27.95, 5, 3, 4, 
5, 4, 3, 25, 25, 27, 29, 25.5, 28.5, 5.12, 4.95, 5, 4.5, 5.12, 
5, 15, 16, 16, 14.99, 15.5, 16, 5, 6.5, 5.5, 7.5, 6, 5), change = c(0, 
16.69449082, 14.30615165, 12.640801, -33.33333333, -7.666666667, 
0, 42.71428571, -30.03003003, -3.433476395, 18.51851852, -0.125, 
0, -20.02002002, -25.03128911, 50.08347245, 22.24694105, -11.28298453, 
0, 1.601601602, -11.42857143, -22.24694105, -14.30615165, 66.77796327, 
0, -22.42242242, 12.90322581, 13.71428571, -54.77386935, 23.11111111, 
0, 12.78195489, 66.66666667, 19.33333333, -0.558659218, -21.46067416, 
0, 16.55738791, -2.841070515, 5.848295222, 5.525167136, -8.372166082, 
0, 8.047901107, 7.44845668, 6.932120674, 6.482730007, 6.088057666, 
0, 12.51564456, 0.667408231, 0.552486188, 9.78021978, 1.601601602, 
0, 29.62962963, -11.42857143, 25.80645161, -30.76923077, 29.62962963, 
0, 1.93236715, 4.265402844, 54.54545455, 4.411764706, 1.408450704, 
0, 1.147776184, 27.23404255, 0.334448161, -0.111111111, -22.24694105, 
0, 5.802901451, -19.66903073, 5.885815185, 5.558643691, -21.06371775, 
0, 0.06684492, 1.20240481, 19.9339934, 4.56796918, 163.1578947, 
0, 16.66666667, 14.28571429, -12.5, 28.57142857, 11.11111111, 
0, 10, 9.090909091, -8.333333333, 9.090909091, -25, 0, 20, 16.66666667, 
7.142857143, -33.33333333, 0, 0, -9.132420091, 0.40201005, 5.105105105, 
4.285714286, -9.132420091, 0, 7.142857143, -6.666666667, 14.28571429, 
-15.625, 3.518518519, 0, -40, 33.33333333, 25, -20, -25, 0, 0, 
8, 7.407407407, -12.06896552, 11.76470588, -82.03508772, 0, 1.01010101, 
-10, 13.77777778, -2.34375, 0, 6.666666667, 0, -6.3125, 3.402268179, 
3.225806452, 0, 30, -15.38461538, 36.36363636, -20, -16.66666667
), Dates = c("1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", 
"9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", 
"7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", 
"1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -144L))
```

Here is the code:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
  vertical_layout: fill

runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(pins)
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)


test_data  <- #dput data

```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

selectInput("Toys",
            label = "Toys",
            choices = c("ALL",unique(sort(test_data$Toys))),
            selected = "ALL")

selectInput("Manufacturer",
                label = "Manufacturer",
                choices = c("ALL", test_data %>% 
                          dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>% 
                          dplyr::arrange(Manufacturer)),
            selected = c("ALL"), 
            multiple = TRUE)
                  

dateRangeInput(inputId = "Dates",
               label = "Date Range",
               start = Sys.Date() %m+% years(-1),
               end = Sys.Date(),
               format = 'yyyy-mm')

```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)

observe({
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "Manufacturer", 
                        choices = test_data[test_data$Toys ==input$Toys, 
                                            "Manufacturer"] %>% 
                          append('ALL', after = 0))
  
})


Toys_reactive <- reactive({ 
  
      test_data[(input$Manufacturer == "ALL" |
                                    test_data$Manufacturer == input$Manufacturer) & 
                                   (input$Toys == "ALL" | 
                                      test_data$Toys == input$Toys),,drop = FALSE]
    })

chart_height <- reactive({Toys_reactive() %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>%
        dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
        unique %>%
        nrow * 130})

 output$plot <- renderPlotly({
       p <- Toys_reactive() %>% 
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = Dates, y = Price, text = paste(paste0("Price: $", sprintf("%.2f", Price)),"<br> Date: ", Dates), group = Manufacturer)) + 
          geom_point(size = 1.5) + 
          geom_line() + 
         facet_wrap(~Manufacturer, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
          theme_bw() + 
           theme(
            title = element_text(colour='black'),
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.85)),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.1),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing = unit(0.45,"cm")
           ) #ensuring that plots render properly
       ggplotly(p, height = chart_height(), tooltip = "text", xaxis = list(automargin = T)) %>% layout(margin=list(b=25))
        
     })
    #Renders the plot above with the proper height
    renderUI({
      plotlyOutput("plot", height = "100%")
    })
    
```

{.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Table 1
```{r}

downloadLink('downBtn2', 'Download all data')
output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
  downloadButton("downBtn2", "Example.csvv")
})

output$downBtn2 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    "Example.csv"
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(Toys_reactive(), file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)

DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE,
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                           buttons = c('excel'),
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})

```


### Heat Map

```{r}
xtickresize <- reactive({pmin(11,125/nrow(unique(Toys_reactive() %>% 
                                                   select(Manufacturer))))})

renderPlotly({p <- ggplot(Toys_reactive() %>% 
                            dplyr::group_by(Toys, Manufacturer) %>% 
                            dplyr::summarize(change = sum(change, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  aes(x = Manufacturer, y = Toys)) + 
                    geom_tile(aes(fill = change)) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
                                                     angle = 45, 
                                                     hjust = 1, 
                                                     size =xtickresize()),
                          axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(0.9)),
                          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.title.y = element_blank(), legend.key.size = unit(0.5,'cm')) +
                    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1)

    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(autosize = T)
  }) 

```


### Table 2
```{r}


# downloadLink('downBtn', 'Download all data')
# output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
#   downloadButton("downBtn", "Example.csvv")
# })
# 
# output$downBtn <- downloadHandler(
#   filename = function() {
#     "Example.csv"
#   },
#   content = function(file) {
#     write.csv(Toys_reactive(), file, row.names = FALSE)
#   }
# )


DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE, 
          caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
            style = 'caption-side: top;', paste(output$downBtn)), 
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                           buttons = c('excel'),
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})
````

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

As you can see, the Manufacturer drop down is blank. I would prefer for the Manufacturer dashboard to first select "ALL" once it the application is loaded.

Anyone know how this would be done? **I tried to set `selected = "ALL"` for the `selectInput` statement for the manufacturer drop down**, but that did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic, multiple input drop down, with a default starting value in R shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510162/dynamic-multiple-input-drop-down-with-a-default-starting-value-in-r-shiny-app)

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work unfortunately. It still defaults to blank. I actually put this in the original question as well. I've bolded it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting, I have found the problem. The problem was with the observe statement in the code:

```
observe({
          updateSelectInput(inputId = "Manufacturer",
                            choices = test_data[test_data$Toys ==input$Toys,"Manufacturer"] %>%
                              append('ALL', after = 0))
    
    })
```

Instead of including parameter `selected = 'ALL'` in the original `selectInput` statement, it should go in the `updateSelectInput` in the observe statement. This was causing the manufacturer dropdown to be blank during initial load of the application. It now works as expected.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
  vertical_layout: fill

runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(pins)
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)


test_data  <- #data included in the original question
```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

selectInput("Toys",
            label = "Toys",
            choices = unique(sort(test_data$Toys)),
            selected = "Slinky")

selectInput("Manufacturer",
                label = "Manufacturer",
                choices =
                 as.vector(unlist(unique(test_data %>% 
                                           dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>% 
                                           dplyr::arrange(Manufacturer)))),
            multiple = TRUE)
                  

dateRangeInput(inputId = "Dates",
               label = "Date Range",
               start = Sys.Date() %m+% years(-1),
               end = Sys.Date(),
               format = 'yyyy-mm')

```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)

observe({
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "Manufacturer",
                        choices = test_data[test_data$Toys ==input$Toys,"Manufacturer"] %>%
                          append('ALL', after = 0),
                        selected = 'ALL')

})


Toys_reactive <- reactive({
  if(input$Manufacturer == "ALL"){
    Toys_reactive <- test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys)
  }
  else if(length(unique(test_data$Manufacturer)) >= 1){
    Toys_reactive = NULL
    for(i in input$Manufacturer){
      subset_toys <- test_data %>% 
        dplyr::filter(Manufacturer == i & Toys == input$Toys)
      Toys_reactive <- rbind(Toys_reactive, subset_toys)
    }
  }
  Toys_reactive
})



chart_height <- reactive({Toys_reactive() %>%
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>%
        dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
        unique %>%
        nrow * 130})

 output$plot <- renderPlotly({
       p <- Toys_reactive() %>% 
        dplyr::filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = Dates, y = Price, text = paste(paste0("Price: $", sprintf("%.2f", Price)),"<br> Date: ", Dates), group = Manufacturer)) + 
          geom_point(size = 1.5) + 
          geom_line() + 
         facet_wrap(~Manufacturer, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
          theme_bw() + 
           theme(
            title = element_text(colour='black'),
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.85)),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.1),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing = unit(0.45,"cm")
           ) #ensuring that plots render properly
       ggplotly(p, height = chart_height(), tooltip = "text", xaxis = list(automargin = T)) %>% layout(margin=list(b=25))
        
     })
    #Renders the plot above with the proper height
    renderUI({
      plotlyOutput("plot", height = "100%")
    })
    
```

{.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Table 1
```{r}

downloadLink('downBtn2', 'Download all data')
output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
  downloadButton("downBtn2", "Example.csvv")
})

output$downBtn2 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    "Example.csv"
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(Toys_reactive(), file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)

DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE,
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                           buttons = c('excel'),
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})

```


### Heat Map

```{r}
xtickresize <- reactive({pmin(11,125/nrow(unique(Toys_reactive() %>% 
                                                   select(Manufacturer))))})

renderPlotly({p <- ggplot(Toys_reactive() %>% 
                            dplyr::group_by(Toys, Manufacturer) %>% 
                            dplyr::summarize(change = sum(change, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  aes(x = Manufacturer, y = Toys)) + 
                    geom_tile(aes(fill = change)) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
                                                     angle = 45, 
                                                     hjust = 1, 
                                                     size =xtickresize()),
                          axis.text.y = element_text(size = rel(0.9)),
                          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                          axis.title.y = element_blank(), legend.key.size = unit(0.5,'cm')) +
                    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1)

    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(autosize = T)
  }) 

```


### Table 2
```{r}


# downloadLink('downBtn', 'Download all data')
# output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
#   downloadButton("downBtn", "Example.csvv")
# })
# 
# output$downBtn <- downloadHandler(
#   filename = function() {
#     "Example.csv"
#   },
#   content = function(file) {
#     write.csv(Toys_reactive(), file, row.names = FALSE)
#   }
# )


DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(Toys_reactive(),
          fillContainer = TRUE, 
          caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
            style = 'caption-side: top;', paste(output$downBtn)), 
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',
                           buttons = c('excel'),
                           lengthMenu = list(c(15,30,45,-1),
                                             c(15,30,45,"All"))))

})
````

Answer (score -1):

The link I provided in the comment above provides the answer you need.  You just didn't implement it correctly.  To specify a default for a `selectInput` with `multiple=TRUE`, you need to provide a *vector* of default values, not a *scalar*.

Here is a MWE to demonstrate.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-fluidPage(
       selectInput("single", "Select one:", LETTERS[1:4], selected="A"),
       selectInput("multi", "Select many:", LETTERS[1:8], multiple=TRUE, selected=c("A", "C")),
       selectInput("anotherMulti", "Select many:", LETTERS[1:8], multiple=TRUE, selected=c("A"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Really, this should be a comment, not an answer, but comments can't be formated (so it would be less easy to read) nor include images.

**Update**

Following OP's mention of `flexdashboard`, I get the following after importing the three `selectInput`s above into an RMarkdown document using `dashboard`:

[image]

This was my document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill

runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Demo

```{r}
selectInput("single", "Select one:", LETTERS[1:4], selected="A")
selectInput(
  "multi", 
  "Select many:", 
  LETTERS[1:8], 
  multiple=TRUE, 
  selected=c("A", "C")
)
selectInput(
  "anotherMulti", 
  "Select many:", 
  LETTERS[1:8],
  multiple=TRUE, 
  selected=c("A")
)
```
````

Perhaps creating a truly *minimal* reproducible example might help to isolate the real problem?

Comment: This still doesn't work. I believe this might be a flexdashboard issue unfortunately.